# What kind of data, We can process through Spark ?? Structured/unstructured/semi-structured?

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am new in map reduce and spark, In Big Data world there are different type Of Data.
Example
40,000 google searches/second
6000 tweets/second
5,00,000 New FB users every day,4 PB/day
35 Amazon orders/second 
5000 sensors/flight engine producing 10GB/sec...

for streaming process we have map reduce and spark framework. So what kind of data we can process through spark framework ??

Answer (score 0):

> for streaming process we have map reduce and spark framework. So what
>   kind of data we can process through spark framework ??

You can process structure and Semi structure data easily with Spark. Spark has also ability to process unstructured data if data parsing is possible.

From your question, if you are referring map reduce with *Hadoop MapReduce engine then it is not possible to use it in Streaming of data*. 
Yes, you can use Spark for Data streaming and Real time processing.

Answer (score 0):

Web data like google searches, Facebook posts, Tweets, amazon orders, etc can be sent to Kafka and data from Kafka can be consumed by spark streaming application in a real time fashion.

Here Kafka is - 
distributed publish-subscribe messaging system that receives data from disparate source systems and makes the data available to target systems in real time.

```
Web Application —> Kafka topic (partition-1)
Web Application —> Kafka topic (partition-2)
Web Application —> Kafka topic (partition-3)
—
—
Web Application —> Kafka topic (partition-n)


Then,

Kafka topic —> Spark Streaming App —> (hive table, hdfs file, hbase, etc)
```

Hope this is helpful.